# Uploading to Cloudinary using Multer

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to have files uploaded using Multer, and then sending them to Cloudinary to store them.

When sending to a local directory its successful, but when sending to Cloudinary 
I receive no feedback from the program or cloudinary.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
      res.render('index.html');
    });

    app.post('/upload', multer(multerConfig).single('photo'),function(req, res){
        cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path,{tags:'basic_sample'},function(result){
            console.log(result)
        });
    };
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using mutler, I have used connect-multiparty and it couldn't be more perfect.

https://github.com/highskillzz/Gotemps/

This is the project I have used it for. But I have used it for file uploading so just care of that aspect

Comment: Okay cool, I'll make sure to check it out in future projects .